# Any way to get munin plugin output to dstat?

Tags: performance-monitoring, munin

The two tools are great with plugins and many available out of the box metrics.

I was wondering if there is a way to get output of munin into dstat or a similar tool (real time output vs munin's periodical graph).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use munin plugins for plotting rather than passing munin output to an external application. Set short period (ex. 60 sec.) by setting appropriate `update_rate`. Here is an example of trivial plugin

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
   config)
        cat <<'EOM'
graph_title Load average
graph_vlabel load
load.label load
EOM
        exit 0;;
esac

echo -n "load.value "
cut -d' ' -f2  /proc/loadavg
```

which plots the load average. For more complicated ones, look here (http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins). If you want to plot multigraphs, read this(http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MultigraphSampleOutput).

Comment: I understand, but this approach is great if simply better average or more frequent update is required. However, in this case the need is to see real time changes